# Exception thrown with stof - C++

Tags: c++, file, csv, exception

so I have a program that opens a csv file and does a bunch of operations with it. Now I need to change it so that it opens a text file that lists the name of files I want to use inside it, and then loop to do the same operations until it has done it for all these files instead of just one file like before. I'm quite confused because I don't see anything wrong with this snippet of code as it worked just fine previously when reading from a single file.

I discard the first line of every csv file to store them as column headers, before proceeding to read the rest of the file line by line. My program crashes when it reaches this line:

```
getline(datafile, unusedline, '\n');
```

With the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid argument' what(): stof
```

I assume that it crashes here because ive added cout statements to show me where the program stops running and this is where it crashes. I have a lot of code so ill try and make it as readable as possible

```
ifstream infile("data\\met_index.txt"); //Open the text file thats lists the csv files needed

    if(!infile) //Exits the program and outputs this message if the file is not found
    {

        cout << "File not found.";

        return -1;

    }

    Vector<string> headers;

    while(getline(infile, files))
    {

        ifstream datafile(files.c_str());
        if(!datafile) //Exits the program and outputs this message if the file is not found
        {

            cout << "File not found.";

            return -1;

        }
        cout << "File: " << files << endl;

        cout << "Reached here so far: " << endl;

        string unusedline;
        string line;
        string token2;
        getline(datafile, unusedline, '\n');
        cout << "Testing for the first line: " << unusedline << endl;
        stringstream headers2(unusedline);
        cout << "Testing for crash" << endl;
        //This is where it crashes, after printing the above statement
        while(getline(headers2, token2, ','))
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < headers.vecsize(); x++){
            headers.add(token2);
            cout << headers[x] << endl;
            }


        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve] so we can analyze your problem properly.

Comment: `std::cout` buffers it's data, so what you see on the screen is not necessarily an indication of where it crashed. Try changing `cout` to `cerr`

Comment: According to your comments, your program crashes *after* the "Test for crash" statement, so it obviously doesn't crash at the ``getline(datafile, unusedline, '\n');`` line, because that's *before* that statement. Most likely it crashes somewhere in the header.add(token2); call, probably within a stof call that is called with an string that does not represent a float. 

Also, using a proper debugger instead of just relying on cout would help you a lot when debugging. For example, the debugger would show you the exact line where the crash happens.

Comment: @Baruch The OP was careful to end `cout <<` statments with `endl` so in this case all output will be flushed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Since your posted code includes no calls to `stof`, I assume that the crash is actually in `headers.add(token2);`. If `stof` throws an `invalid_argument` exception it means that it has been given something which cannot be converted into a floating point number.

In other words it looks like the problem is with your data, not with your code, or maybe the code doesn't match up to the data.

PS in general using a debugger is easier than adding `cout <<` statements to your code.

Comment: Using a debugger is defiantly more accurate, not necessarily easier. But even if using prints for debugging, `cerr` should be used, not `cout`